# OTP only login for Django

Tags: django, django-login

I would like to have OTP only for authentication. I read about `django-otp` and `django-two-factor-auth` but they are both for two-factor authentication. I read the examples in the github and unfortunately do not know if it is possible to make if OTP authenticated only based on limited experience.

I was thinking about using native python and Javascript for this, but I guess decorators `@login-required` requires Django Login?

I would also like to log the user activity with Matomo`django-analytics` in the future. I am not sure if I have to use Django Login in order to track activities later.

Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

For OTP-LOGIN you must use the third-party API, Which will send OTP and Verify,
Because in Django there is no inbuilt library, Just you can try to generate OTP and Share with the user and Verify at your end manually this can be done.

For LoginRequired decorator, Your user must be a USER in the Admin portal.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to show another view if only correcting filling out correct info in previous view, without having to store USER in a database, like a more native version of Django-login?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use email for OTP, it would be better to use [django core mailing library](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/). Also there are third party APIs [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python) for sending SMS.